# First day between two dates in php

Tags: php, date, intervals

I want to get the first day of the year *between two dates*, for example if **date1** is **2015-02-01** and **date2** is **2017-01-07**, the answer will be [**2015-01-01**, **2016-01-01**, **2017-01-01**]

I have tried the following for the data above:

```
$date1_rep_val=2015-02-01;
$date2_rep_val=2017-01-07;
$date1=(new DateTime("$date1_rep_val"))->modify('first day of this year');
$date2=(new DateTime("$date2_rep_val"))->modify('first day of this year');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year');
$period   = new DatePeriod($date1, $interval, $date2);
$f_cnt=0;
foreach ($period as $dt) 
  {
   $tick_data[$f_cnt]= $dt->format("Y-m-d");
   echo $tick_data[$f_cnt];
   $f_cnt++;
  }
```

But, the above code gives only **2015-01-01** and **2016-01-01** it is not giving **2017-01-01** , thanks for any help related to this question.

Comment: `$date2=(new DateTime("$date2_rep_val"));`

Comment: `2015-01-01` is NOT between `2015-02-01` and `2017-01-07`

Comment: Why not take the year of each dates, loop and add `01-01`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
$date1 = '2015-02-01';
$date2 = '2017-01-07';
$y1 = substr($date1, 0, 4);
$y2 = substr($date2, 0, 4);
$res= array();
for ($y = $y1; $y <= $y2; $y++) {
    $res[] = $y . "-01-01";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate (but essentially the same) solution with DateTime type using:

```
$date1_rep_val='2015-02-01';
$date2_rep_val='2017-01-07';

$date1 = new DateTime($date1_rep_val);
$date2 = new DateTime($date2_rep_val);

$year1 = $date1->format('Y');
$year2 = $date2->format('Y');

$newYearsDates = [];
if (new DateTime($year1 . '-01-01') == $date1) {
    $newYearsDates[] = $date1;
}

if ($year2 > $year1) {
    for ($year = $year1 + 1; $year <= $year2; $year++) {
        $newYearsDates[] = new DateTime($year . '-01-01');    
  }
}

print_r($newYearsDates);
```